# listview null pointer exception on different devices

Tags: android, listview

I m using `ListView` and setting `Adapter` to it on `onResume` method because i want to update 
the list items when activity resumes.
My problem is, this code works perfectly on my Nexus S device
but when i try to run the same `.apk` file on another device, then it throws

`Null Pointer Exception` at 
`listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

on next line

`listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, 
                                    long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ClientInfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", clientIDs[i]);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });`

I don`t no why its not working on diff devices? please help.

Comment: check this line android.R.id.list you are trying to use the list of the android package. Is that what you want? or you have listview element in your xml file?

Comment: Put Exception from Logcat

Comment: @IllegalArgument, i have listview element in xml file.

Answer (score 3):

Change the **listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list)**
to 
**listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.NameOfYourListView)**

check the name of ListView in  **XML** File .

You are actually trying to use default list of Android.

if you are not working in fragment then use context of activity instead of **View** like

this.findViewById(R.id.NameOfYourListView)

Comment: if your listview is in the xml file of main activity  and you are trying to access it in Fragment then do change it to 
this.getActivity().findViewByid(R.id.ListviewName);

Comment: i think you have your listview in XML file of MainActivity. can you make sure it ? is it in Fragment Xml file or in MainActivity XML file ?

Comment: this is a fragment XML file and i m using `LayoutInflater`

Comment: this is a right way of assigning an id to any view **android:id="@+id/list"** _Illagal Argument_ is right about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing wrong id to your listview object.

```
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Replace the **android.R.id.list** field by the id you set in your xml file.

Comment: my id in `xml` file is `android:id="@android:id/list"`. so should i use normal id other than the one i used?

Comment: change it to android:id="@+id/list" if it doesnot work tell me

Comment: @shashi2459 show some more code ensure that view is not null

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        layoutInflater = inflater;

        db = new GirijaCabsSQLiteDB(mContext, db.DATABASE, null, 1);
        clients = db.selectClients();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.client_layout_list, container, false);  listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointer exception which is present only on some device may be caused by lack of id declaration in one of the xml layout.

When you create multiple layout for the same activity to provide a proper aspect for all possible screen size or orientation you have to declare the id in each layout.

If you don't declare the id for a layout the compiler will not throw error or warnings as the resource will be present. All will run smoothly util the application creates the activity with the specific layout which lack of the id declaration: only at that point the activity will crash showing the exception.